# Comment on Facebook social plugin via RestFB

Tags: java, facebook, plugins, restfb

I'm trying to comment with RestFB over a social media plugin like on the page below:
http://www.zuberi.me/2011/facebook-social-plugin-comments.html

But I've got no idea how to do it. I'm able to post and comment a post at my wall with this code:

```
facebookClient.publish("fbid"+"/comments", String.class, Parameter.with("message", "my comment here"));
```

I'm not sure about the `fbid` of the social plugin, and about the permissions, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to post on a Comments Plugin programmatically.